# Variants of the construction "Voilà que je me mets à ..."

Tags: expressions, constructions

> **Voilà que je me mets à** pleurer sans raison apparente.

I usually use the construction above, but I wonder if the following three variants work or not. I assume probably not, though.

> **Me voilà qui me mets à** pleurer sans raison apparente.
>
> **Me voilà me mettant à** pleurer sans raison apparente.
>
> **Me voilà mettant à** pleurer sans raison apparente.

Answer (score 2):

The third form is incorrect. Here *mettre* need to be used with a pronominal form.

The first form is correct although rarer than *voilà que je me mets*, especially here at the first person. Other persons are more common:

> Me voilà qui me mets...
>   Te voilà qui te mets...
>   Le voilà qui se met...
>   Les voilà qui se mettent...

The second form is even rarer and less idiomatic but still correct:

> Me voilà me mettant...
>   Te voilà te mettant...
>   Le voilà se mettant...
>   ...

There is also the colloquial form:

> Voilà pas que je me mets...

and this even more colloquial (but ageing in France) one:

> Voilà-t-y pas que je me mets...

Comment: Aging perhaps in the old Countries, but definitely alive and well in Quebec...

Comment: @Feelew Réponse mise à jpur; merci !

Answer (score 0):

The second seems correct, but the others arn't.

If you talk about yourself you should use "Voilà que je me mets à" anyway.

But then again i have never heard anyone here in a french speaking country using any of the three.